# EF Core Presenting Error on Column Names for Email and PhoneNumber

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I currently have a User entity model that was created through an initial migration. I am trying to add two new columns named 'Email' and 'PhoneNumber'.

When I try to create the new migration I am getting the following error:

`An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Invalid column name 'Email'.
Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber'.`

I have tried reverting my migrations, deleting them and starting fresh, but I am still getting this error.

Any ideas of what could be causing this?

Migration command: `dotnet ef migrations add AddEmailAndPhoneDbMigration -c UsersDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/UserDb`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the provider is not recognizing the columns right, your entity-model or your dbcontext is wrong

Comment: I am just adding two new columns (one is a string and the other an int) to an entity that was already created successfully via an initial migration. Not sure how that would break this.

Comment: Try to save migrate, delete/temp remove old migrations, and then migrate

Comment: Tried all that. Tried dropping the entire database on the server and clearing out all migrations. Here is a gist of the error... it looks like it is trying to read the column in a query before ever creating it: https://gist.github.com/ryanmendoza/20bd39cd31f3c70df416ebc0d4230d66

Comment: Figured it out... when running the migration it is running the app, including any seeding methods kicked off in there. This seems like an EF bug?